# mat-slider how to trigger on changed value immediately and not on released?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm trying to use a  element to change the current image displayed like a slide show.

```
<mat-slider  (change) ="update360($event,product)" thumbLabel tickInterval="1" min="1" max="24" step="1" fxFlex="100"></mat-slider>
```

This code trigs the method update360 only when I release the mouse, but I want to trig the method every time the value is changed! How Can I do?
So If I'm correctly on value = 1 and I move on the right until 10, I want that method is trigged 10 times!
How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

use `input` event instead.

```
<mat-slider (input)="update360($event,product)"></mat-slider>
```

Documentation: https://material.angular.io/components/slider/api#MatSlider